# How can I import a custom library into a Ionic 6/VueJs 3 Project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, ionic6

So I'm new to typescript, Ionic 6 and Vue Js.

I've created a multiapp project with Ionic 6/VueJs 3.

Here is the structure:

```
{
  "defaultProject": "app1",
  "projects": {
    "app1": {
      "name": "app1",
      "integrations": {
        "capacitor": {}
      },
      "type": "vue",
      "root": "apps\\app1"
    },
    "app2": {
      "name": "app2",
      "integrations": {
        "capacitor": {}
      },
      "type": "vue",
      "root": "apps\\app2"
    },
    "common": {
      "name": "common",
      "integrations": {
        "capacitor": {}
      },
      "type": "vue",
      "root": "library\\common"
    }
  }
}
```

I've managed to export the library with rollup -c

Now I'm wondering how to use it.

I've tried using npm link and importing it with...

However I'm getting compilation errors, when I try to use it as the compiled module does not include the types...

I'm getting **TS7006: Parameter 'app' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

I know that if I **disable the strict mode**, I can make it work, but that it is not a solution.

I can provide more info if required.

Comment: Did you make the project from a proper Vue3+Typesctipr template or from scratch? If from scratch then I recomment making a new one from template, see how it works, and migrate everything needed it the way you like more (template may have better folder structure, but migraion to it may be harder then importing needed things)

Comment: I used templates and also the folder structure is the recommended one for multi app projects...